# How can I change class value in multiprocessing without Queues?

Tags: python, global-variables, multiprocessing

Can I change value `var1` inside new process?

```
class A: 
    var1 = 0 

method2(): 
    var1 += 1 

method1(): 
    p = multiprocessing.Process(method2) 
    p.start() 
    p.join() 
    print(var1)
```

Call method1(). `var1` has not changed.

```
A().method1()
>>> 0
```

By the way, I can't use `Queues`

Comment: Firstly, please post proper code; this won't even run. Secondly, explain *why" you "can't use Queues".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of python's GIL, multiprocessing can only be used whith completely separate tasks, and no shared memory. So When you create your process `p`, it copies the value of your instance of `A`, and change the value of `var1` in this copied instance, leaving the original instance unmodified.
But you still can make it happend by using multiprocessing shared Array/Value:

from https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

```
from multiprocessing import Value

var1 = Value('d', 0.0)
```

You need to ensure that differents processes won't access the same variable at the same time, and use a `Lock`. Hopefuly, all the shared variable available in the `multiprocessing` module are paired with a Lock.

To access the lock :

```
var1.acquire() # get the lock
# do stuff
var1.release() # don't forget to release it
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: It helped! Thanks!

Comment: Hi, CoMartel! Changing var1 in another Process is possible only if I use this data type (multiprocessing.Value?) I mean, if it is just an int or a list, the value will not change?

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam yes, "classic" types are local to one process, and changes in one process won't be extended to other processes. There are however a few types you can share between processes, like `Array` (from multiprocessing module) and sharedctypes : https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.sharedctypes

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much.
And what is about pandas.DataFrame? It will not change too?

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam no, pandas DataFrame won't change either